# Maximum of element from List based on the another one

Tags: java, list, optimization, arraylist, java-stream

I need to find out the maximum of element that belongs to another one. Giving you an example is the clearest.

I have the `List<String> lines` containing the following data:

```
1, 1, A, Aaa ...
1, 2, A, Aaa ...
1, 4, A, Aaa ...
2, 5, B, Bbb ...
2, 3, B, Bbb ...
3, 6, C, Ccc ...
4, 7, D, Ddd ...
5, 8, E, Eee ...
1, 9, A, Aaa ...
4, 10, D, Ddd ...
```

To be clear, 2 couples of numbers are never same, so you never get:

```
1, 9, A, Aaa ...
1, 9, B, Bbb ...
```

My goal is to extract lines with the maximum of second row that belongs to the first row. To be exact these lines:

```
1, 9, A, Aaa ...
2, 5, B, Bbb ...
3, 6, C, Ccc ...
4, 10, D, Ddd ...
5, 8, E, Eee ...
```

To prove you it's not a homework, I have made the solution using multiple `for-loop` to find the maximum and storing to variable. However I don't know if it works, because of huge amount of data (`200 000+`) tested.

```
// List "lines" is declared above

List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> maxValues = new ArrayList<>();

// clear and separate to clear comparable parts
for (String s: lines) {
    String parts[] = s.trim().replace("\"", "").split(";");
    List newList = Arrays.asList(parts);
    data.add(newList);
}

// naïve algorithm to find the maximum dependent to the another one
// not sure if working
for (List l: data) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(l.get(0).toString());
    int max = 0;    
    List<String> tempMaxValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(l.get(0).toString()) == id) {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(l.get(1).toString());
            if (temp > max) {
               max = temp;
               tempMaxValues = l;
            }
        }
    }
    maxValues.add(tempMaxValues);
}
```

Moreover I need do more calculations in consequence. Is possible to reach my desired result only with `Stream` or a much simplier method? I am getting lost and confused even in my code.

Comment: there's nothig bad in asking help for a homework, bad is that no effort is made to produce own solution :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the meaning of `with the maximum of second row that belongs to the first row`. Can you expand on this?

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou: It's not a homework indeed. If so, I feel free to admit that. :) I do this as the challenge I met in my previous work, but we used SQL that is better in this case.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: That's why there is a sample input and the desired result.

Comment: why don't you have a `Map` where for each distinct "first" value is stored the whole line for that value?

Comment: Best here is to use a Map and add to the value

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Do you mean `Map<Integer ,List<String>>`? If so, I agree, but I want to store there the value according my conditions, not the first one.

Comment: Yep use a map. And if you are going to have a lot of data as you have said, dont read the complete file into a line array. Read the file line by line and update your map accordingly. Edit: Use Map<String, Integer> with string beeing Aaa, Bbb.... and Integer beeing your value you want to max.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I can see your example, but I think it needs clarification. For example, how are ties broken? E.g. if `1 9 B Bbb...` was also present would this be chosen over `1 9 A Aaa...`? Also what order should the answer be in? Sorted by the first number or in the order encountered in `lines`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: This never happens. Two values are never same with another ones. I edit that, thanks for a hint :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functional terms, what you want is to group each list value by their first element and select only the maximum value with regard to the second element. Using the Stream API, you can:

1. Use the [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector to group by the list by their first element.
2. The downstream collector applied to all values classified to the same key is [`maxBy(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) that selects only the maximum of the collected values. In this case, the comparator compares the second value of each list as an `int` with the help of the built-in [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).
3. Since `maxBy` returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in the case that no values were collected, we wrap it with a call to [`collectingAndThen(finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) where the finisher retrieves the `Optional` value (we know in this case that at least one value will have been classified) by calling [`Optional.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--).
4. Finally, we keep only the [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) from the resulting `Map<String, List<String>>` and, since this returns a `Collection<List<String>>`, we create an `ArrayList` based on it.

Sample code:

```
List<List<String>> maxValues = new ArrayList<>(
    data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            l -> l.get(0),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(1)))), 
                Optional::get
            )
        ))
        .values()
);
```

which results in

```
[1, 9, A, Aaa], [2, 5, B, Bbb], [3, 6, C, Ccc], [4, 10, D, Ddd], [5, 8, E, Eee]]
```

for your sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try it. This king of complex stream is quite complicated for me and I will need to spend a time over it to understand. Would you also suggest me the best way to learn streams except trying and trying?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Oracle has a nice tutorial here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/ to start working with the Stream API.

Answer (score 3):

For me, "naïve" is something like using [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to collect lines by unique keys (id values):

```
static final Function<List<String>, Integer> GET_ID = l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(0));
static final Function<List<String>, Integer> GET_TEMP = l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(1));

Map<Integer, List<String>> max = new TreeMap<>(); 
for (List<String> l : data) 
    max.merge(GET_ID.apply(l), l, BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(GET_TEMP)));
```

After that, only lines having maximum second value among lines of the same id, will be stored in `max` map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I try it :) Why have you used a `TreeMap`? Would you explain me please?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis `TreeMap` returns entries ordered by key (in your case, by "id"), and implements `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap`, allowing to range query, next/previous key etc

Comment: Pretty succinct +1. I think you might be able to make it even shorter by combining `merge` with `BinaryOperator.maxBy`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use `toMap` collector and `BinaryOperator.maxBy` as a merge function. Given `List<String> lines` as the input, you can get the best strings this way:

```
Collection<String> maxValues = lines.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                l -> l.split(",", 2)[0], 
                l -> l,
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(
                        l -> Integer.parseInt(l.split(",", 3)[1].trim()))))).values();
System.out.println(maxValues);
```

Probably it looks better when merging operator is extracted to the variable:

```
BinaryOperator<String> maxBy = BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(
            l -> Integer.parseInt(l.split(",", 3)[1].trim())));
Collection<String> maxValues = lines.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.split(",", 2)[0], l -> l, maxBy)).values();
```

If you have `List<List<String>>` as the input (splitting and trimming is already performed), you can find `Collection<List<String>>` in the following way:

```
BinaryOperator<List<String>> maxBy = BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator
        .comparingInt(l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(1))));
Collection<List<String>> maxValues = lines.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.get(0), l -> l, maxBy)).values();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you introduce me more to `BinaryOperator`? Any page where is it explained well?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, official [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If i did well understand you can solve your problem using an other method ;
first : create a class which contains your data (objects)

```
public class DataObject {
      int n1;
      int n2;
      String s1;
      String s2;
}
```

And create you list of objects :

```
List<DataObject> data = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
List maxVal = new ArrayList<DataObject>();

for (DataObject dO1 : data){
    for (DataObject dO2 : data){
        if (dO1.n1 == dO2.n2){
           /*test to determin the max value and 
            *store it in maxVal
           */
        }
    }
}
```

And that will access to data much more easier, Or did i get it wrong ?

Comment: I have been thinking about the way to store data into Objects. However I declined it because of external factors I apply to the input file (changing the order of columns). So it would make troubles with storing data into Objects. Moreover you have wrong comparator, you have use the double `==`